# Vector bundle, why is this not the definition?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I have to say first that I haven't read enough about vector bundles because currently I don't have time for it. But I hope that the question isn't that much trivial.

---

Why don't define the vector bundle of the $k$-manifold $M$ simply as follows?

> It is the topological space $M\times \mathbb R^k$, endowed with the product topology and a projection $\pi: M\times \mathbb R^k \to M$, (which is continuous because it maps open sets to open sets,) and further we require that the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$, for $p \in M$, has the  vector space structure of $\mathbb R^k$.

The local trivialisation is now simply $\pi$. Why isn't that enough ? what did I miss ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the" vector bundle?  There are usually many, and that's important.  Your definition seems to give only the trivial bundle.

Comment: Because it is then mostly useless, since it doesn't even include tangent bundle of spheres.

Comment: Most tangent bundles aren't direct products.

Comment: @Randall Direct products you mean $M\times \mathbb R^k$

Comment: @Physor correct.

Comment: So I think it is the same mistake as taking every $k$-manifold to be as $\mathbb R^k$, where it should be so only locally, right ? Further, in the definition I had to say, it is a topological space which is locally homeomorphic to $U\times\mathbb R^k$, for $U \subset M$ open

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The tangent bundle is locally a product, but usually not globally.  That's the whole point of a bundle.

Comment: The wikipedia article on [fiber bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) explains it pretty well.

Comment: Check the open set definition of continuity.

Answer (score 3):

(There are many different vector bundles on a given space, so I'm not sure if by "*the* vector bundle" you really mean the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle). In any case, the tangent bundle is an example of a vector bundle that doesn't fit your definition.)

Informally, the tangent bundle is the space of vectors "tangent to" or "inside" a manifold. This looks like a product space *locally*, but it can have a different global topological structure.

The [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) demonstrates this difference. When $M=S^2$, there is no continuous map $M\to TM$ that assigns a nonzero vector to every point. If $TM$ were just a product space $M\times \Bbb R^k$, we could trivially assign a nonzero vector to each point using a map like $x\mapsto(x,(1,...))$. The tangent bundle captures the requirement that our tangent vector must vary continuously *and remain tangent to $M$* as we move around on $M$.

Comment: I don't know why you introduce a map here (do you require it to be smooth ?), could you elaborate ?

Comment: Edited to clarify. The point is that the hairy ball theorem demonstrates a difference between the trivial vector bundle (which is what you defined) and the "correct" tangent bundle.